# Call from a dataframe using a plot in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 407 observations of 14 variables. Using ggplot2 or other graphics I can easily create a scatterplot of one of the variables against another to allow me to observe patterns.

I would like to be able to highlight some of the points in the scatterplot that are of interest because of the pattern they make within the plot and then call the associated information from the dataframe. Is there a package that can do this?

There are no other variables within the dataframe that would allow me to distinguish the group of interesting points in the plot. This would make the problem much simpler.

I am aware that this may be a bigger question than I think it is and I am grateful for any pointers in the right direction!

Many thanks!
Nicki

Comment: Thats what I mean yes and it would be possible to stick it in Illustrator or similar and colour the points but then I cant find out what the points are from the database to follow up on why they made the pattern, if that makes any sense! I think some of the options below are what Im looking for, thank you for your comment though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options: `identify()` in base R and the `iplots` package.

First, you can use `identify()` to identify and label points on a `plot()` as you click on them:

```
data(cars)
plot(cars)
interesting <- identify(cars)
```

Now if we click on the plot, it will search for the nearest data point, return its index, and, by default (unless we add the plot = FALSE argument), label that point with its index.

[image]

We stop the identification process by clicking the secondary mouse button and selecting ‘Stop’ from the menu, or by selecting ‘Stop’ on the graphics window.  Since we've stored the output in a variable named interesting, we can easily examine the points:

```
cars[interesting,]
#    speed dist
# 19    13   46
# 23    14   80
# 44    22   66
```

The `iplots` package, which does really nice interactive linked plots, provides a fancier solution:

```
library(iplots)
data(iris)
iplot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Length)
ihist(iris$Sepal.Width)
```

Using iplots, you can highlight data on one plot and have them change colors on all plots.  Here I have selected the red points in the lower plot, changing their color on both plots.

[image]

After highlighting a subset of data, we can determine the currently selected points with `iset.selected()`, as in:

```
iris[iset.selected(),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
# 54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
# etc
```

Since you have 14 variables, mutiple `iplot()` scatterplots might be more effective than using `identify()`.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, I discovered identify() and locator() yesterday but the explanations were nowhere near as good as this! I have managed to get the above to work but the only thing is that I have so many points clustered on top of each other that it is impossible to select them all. If you know of any way that either of these two functions will let me select all the points in a certain range that would be great? Otherwise I will still find the method you have explained very helpful for regular exploratory analysis!

Comment: PS - I also tried iplots - Brilliant wee package! but same problem.

Comment: iplots works by selecting a rectangular area not by clicking, so overlap should not be an issue unless you only want some of those points, in which case `jitter()` is always an option to reduce overlap: `iplot(jitter(iris$Sepal.Length),jitter(iris$Petal.Length))`.  Beyond jitter, iplots has useful actions in the view menu (show only selected, change range of axis) that should help.  Ultimately you may need to select and store the points bit by bit. `firstgroup <- iset.selected()` etc.  (btw, you might consider upvoting or chosing useful answers here)

Comment: Selected useful answer. I dont have enough reputation yet to upvote - just a newbie :( Thanks again for your help - Im still working on it....

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to interact with a scatter plot matrices. I dont' konw how you can do this using `ggplot2` but using lattice you can easily do it with `trellis.focus`..

You can try this for example :

```
super.sym <- trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol")
splom(~iris[1:4], groups = Species, data = iris,      ## splom will draw scatter plots
       panel = panel.superpose,                       ## in iris data since you don't provide 
      key = list(title = "Three Varieties of Iris",   ## reproducible example
                 columns = 3, 
                points = list(pch = super.sym$pch[1:3],
                             col = super.sym$col[1:3]),
                 text = list(c("Setosa", "Versicolor", "Virginica"))))
```

Then, Interaction  part :

```
trellis.focus('panel', 1, 1)                                 ## get the focus
idx <- panel.link.splom(pch=13, cex=0.6, col='green')        ##
```

I choose some points than I escape. I get the results in idx:

```
 idx
[1]  59  21 139  84  78  92
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to do this using ggplot2, but there are other tools that allow for this (often called brushing).

The Rggobi package is an interface to the ggobi program which does brushing (and spinning and lots of other things), you can send your data from R to ggobi, brush in ggobi, then access which points were brushed back in R.

The `TkBrush` function in the TeachingDemos package will create a scatterplot matrix and allow you to brush points (which will show up brushed in every panel) and will return information on the brushed points.  The `HTkIdentify` function in the same package will show information on the point being currently hovered over, this can be multiple lines of info, but the results are not returned.

The iplots package is another option as has been demonstrated by @MattBagg.

It would be possible to create a tool that would figure out which rows of a data frame correspond to the portion of a selected ggplot2 plot, but the data goes through so many steps (and the results are not simple to access/understand) that working back to the original data frame will not be simple.

There are probaly other tools (maybe the R GUIs), but the above should get you started.

Comment: I think "brushing" is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for the tip...will give this a go tonight!